# SQL Server - Sharing database over different boots on local machine

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have 2 bootable partitions on my local machine with Windows 7 running SQL Server 2008 R2 on one and Windows 8 with SQL Server 2012 on the other.

Is it possible to run/attach the same database (created under SQL Server 2008 R2) on both versions of Windows so if I boot up Windows 7 I can run my application against it. And if I run up Windows 8 I can run my application up against that? Would there be any issues if I tried it - i.e logins?

Thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 3):

No, that won't work.

As soon as your SQL Server **2012** version would access one of the database, it will upgrade it to the latest internal database version for the 2012 version.

And once that's happened, the SQL Server **2008 R2** cannot use that database file anymore.

The best solution for this would be to put the database on a separate server which you can access from both your partitions - and consolidate on one SQL Server version (preferably 2012). The other obvious option would be to install the same version of SQL Server on both partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is stored within database, so no you will not have any issues. Just remember to use not only main application database, but use the same meta-databases (aka System dbs).

In fact it works this way on failover clusters.

EDIT:
Haven't noticed you are going to run 2 different db systems. I would recommend you to use exactly the same versions of SQL server.